# Possible null reference argument for parameter 'value' in 'T? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string value)'

Tags: c#, redis, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

Trying to learn .NET Core WebAPI and using Redis. Found [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-token-authentication-using-the-net-core-6-web-api/) example app and tried. Have the same code but I'm getting error below.

PS: Please tell if I need to add Program.cs too.

```
 System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configuration')
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions.DoParse(String configuration, Boolean ignoreUnknown) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConfigurationOptions.cs:line 752
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions.Parse(String configuration, Boolean ignoreUnknown) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConfigurationOptions.cs:line 582
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions.Parse(String configuration) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConfigurationOptions.cs:line 572
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(String configuration, TextWriter log) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 655
   at ApiProject.Cache.ConnectionHelper.<>c.<.cctor>b__0_0() in C:\Users\Mustafa\source\repos\ApiProject\Cache\ConnectionHelper.cs:line 10
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at ApiProject.Cache.ConnectionHelper.get_Connection() in C:\Users\Mustafa\source\repos\ApiProject\Cache\ConnectionHelper.cs:line 18
   at ApiProject.Cache.CacheService.ConfigureRedis() in C:\Users\Mustafa\source\repos\ApiProject\Cache\CacheService.cs:line 14
   at ApiProject.Cache.CacheService..ctor() in C:\Users\Mustafa\source\repos\ApiProject\Cache\CacheService.cs:line 10
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method16(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

ConnectionHelper class:

```
public class ConnectionHelper
    {
        static ConnectionHelper()
        {
            ConnectionHelper.lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
            {
                return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["RedisURL"]);
            });
        }
        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection;
        public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return lazyConnection.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

CacheSerevice class: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);` returns null.

```
public class CacheService : ICacheService
    {
        private IDatabase _db;
        public CacheService()
        {
            ConfigureRedis();
        }
        private void ConfigureRedis()
        {
            _db = ConnectionHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
        }
        public T GetData<T>(string? key)
        {
            var value = _db.StringGet(key);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
            }
            return default;
        }
        public bool SetData<T>(string key, T value, DateTimeOffset expirationTime)
        {
            TimeSpan expiryTime = expirationTime.DateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
            var isSet = _db.StringSet(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value), expiryTime);
            return isSet;
        }
        public object RemoveData(string key)
        {
            bool _isKeyExist = _db.KeyExists(key);
            if (_isKeyExist == true)
            {
                return _db.KeyDelete(key);
            }
            return false;
        }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "RedisURL": "127.0.0.1:6379",
  "JWT": {
    "ValidAudience": "http://localhost:7184",
    "ValidIssuer": "http://localhost:7184",
    "Secret": "JWTAuthentication@777"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ApiTest_Database;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @ConnorStoop `ArgumentNullexception` is not a `NullReferenceexception`

Comment: @kmr What does `ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["RedisURL"]` actually give you in this code?

Comment: @ConnorStoop no but changing RedisURL from appsettings.json works: ` "RedisURL": "127.0.0.1:6379,abortConnect=false" `

Comment: @DavidG `ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["RedisURL"]` takes from appsettings "RedisURL"

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, we no longer get the appsetting value via `ConfigurationManager`, but we use the dependency service, `IConfiguration` or `IOptions<T>` to get the value from appsettings.json. Reference: [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Using `ConfigurationManager` is for .NET framework which get the appsetting value from config file.